# how do I check if the array already contains certain value?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

for some reasons the if statement is not being satisfied...on the first run of the loop it should have resulted to false since i have initiated an empty array which would then be populated once the if statement has been satisfied...please help...so far this is my code

```
$i = 0;
$array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retmes))
{
    $var = $row['id'];

    if(in_array($var, $array, false))
    {
        $array[$i] = $var;
        echo $array[$i];
        $i++;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: But until the next loop the `var` variable has a different value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change your if condition from

```
if(in_array($var, $array, false))
```

to

```
if(!in_array($var, $array))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use negate `!` on if clause

```
if(!in_array($var, $array, false))
```

And more simple format:

```
$array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retmes)) {
    $var = $row['id'];
    if(!in_array($var, $array)) {
        $array[] = $var;
    } else {
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: that did the trick...thank you very much...so what was the last parameter of the in_array for sir?

Comment: @Ralph It's optional. 3rd parameter is default `false` and set to TRUE then function will also check the types.

Comment: @Ralph I think you should read a little bit of documentation before use a function ;) refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php